# Why do designers use "Lorem Ipsum Dolor" to fill space?

Tags: documentation

Why is it traditional to use <strike>Latin</strike> Pseudo-Latin in example pages?  Is actual hypothetical content too confusing?

In [this documentation page](http://whiffdoc.appspot.com/docs/W1100_1300.menus) I snarfed chunks of text from wikipedia -- does this make the page more confusing than if I used Latin or Sanskrit?

Comment: If you mean "lorem ipsum", then it's not really Latin.

Comment: @Pavel: +1, also for other readers, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum for more info.

Comment: Also, Sanskrit doesn't use Roman characters so that would make life a bit more complicated B-)

Comment: @Jed Smith - what passes as legit questions, and what doesn't is one of the great mysteries to me. @Aaron - the question doesn't make sense. It is "traditional" because it is like that by tradition. It would be better if it were stated "should be use something else than lorem ipsum for example pages ?" ...

Comment: There's also a bunch of good info and a lipsum generator at http://lipsum.org/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not even a programing question.

Answer (score 55):

The famous *lorem ipsum dolor* passage is not Latin at all. As explained by [a site dedicated to the passage](http://www.lipsum.com/), it's actually quite historic:

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

As for an explanation of why:

> It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

+1 for allowing me to learn something new, I didn't know this.  Cool.

Comment: Of course, although it isn't latin, it bears some resemblance to it, so people who do know how to read latin, will still be confused by text content ;)

Comment: Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC.

Answer (score 8):

"Lorem ipsum" pseudo-latin is also used as placeholder text, because 1) it is similar in format (consonant/vowel balance, word size, punctuation) to real text but 2) it has no meaning, so clients or others won't be distracted by reading actual words.  Humans have a tendency to automatically read words that are put in front of them, but in an example page you want them to focus on the layout, functionality, etc.

To answer the question about your own site: yes, using wikipedia test could make it more confusing, or at least cause a potential user to think that the application was intended for a particular purpose ("sure, it works for factual entries, but I'm trying to write a novel").

Comment: The ironic thing is that it IS distracting because you see it and think wtf, what language is that? What am I looking at? At least that was my initial reaction. Something like "content goes here" would be much more common sense imo

Answer (score 3):

Just read ["Getting Real"](https://gettingreal.37signals.com/) and they have some good arguments against using any kind of "filler" text in your prototypes/mockups. For example, when designing a user profile page resist the temptation to fill every part of the page with filler text because most commonly, new users won't fill in user details. [They do a much better job explaining](http://37signals.com/svn/archives/001083.php) than I can, but for  most cases it makes more sense to design a page around what it will look like without content.

They also argue (which I tend to agree with) that if you must fill the page with some sort of filler, take the time to write copy that is meaningful in the context of the application rather than using filler text.

Answer (score 2):

I like [37 Signals](https://gettingreal.37signals.com/ch11_Use_Real_Words.php) take on Ipsum text, from [Getting Real](https://gettingreal.37signals.com/index.php):

> Insert actual text instead of lorem
>   ipsum
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor is a trusted friend
>   of designers. Dummy text helps people
>   get what the design will look like
>   once it's fleshed out. But dummy text
>   can be dangerous too.
>
> Lorem ipsum changes the way copy is
>   viewed. It reduces text-based content
>   to a visual design element — a shape
>   of text — instead of what it should
>   be: valuable information someone is
>   going to have to enter and/or read.
>   Dummy text means you won't see the
>   inevitable variations that show up
>   once real information is entered. It
>   means you won't know what it's like to
>   fill out forms on your site. Dummy
>   text is a veil between you and
>   reality.

Comment: Using real text can be useful, but 1) it better be really real -- actual domain-specific data from the client's domain, and 2) be prepared (and allocate time) for discussion of content that springs from the particular text used.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely agree with that, but a good take, I guess.